# Build fails VS 2019 - Could not find part of the path .nib

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019

I can build the solution fine in macOS but in VS 2019 (latest) but cannot build the same solution in VS 2019. Latest stables installed, latest versions of VS 2019 and VS for Mac. I keep getting the error below.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1566  Error reading resource
> '__monotouch_content_Bugreport.storyboardc_fFeedbackNavController.nib'
> -- 'Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Dev\ncsoftware\NCSoftware.iOS\obj\Debug\ibtool-link\Bugreport.storyboardc\FeedbackNavController.nib'.'  NCSoftware.iOS  D:\Dev\ncsoftware\NCSoftware.iOS\CSC    1   Active

Comment: And the nib is there at the location it suggests? Is Bugreport.storyboard one of your storyboards?

Comment: Bugreport.storyboard exists. I'm not sure about the .nib as that is not part of the project, only the storyboard. Within the storyboard the navcontroller exists

Comment: But if you look at the generated stuff in the obj folder when building?

Comment: It's looking for a path with "ib-tool" in it which doesn't exist.

Comment: Does it build in VS for Mac?

Comment: Yes. Only fails on VS 2019. Tried two machines.

Comment: I couldn't understand your question "but in VS 2019 (latest) but cannot build the same solution in VS 2019", could you please rephrase it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue with the last several versions of Visual Studio 2019 and has been broken for about two months. This has been solved with today's update to 16.7.6.